# How to do where condition on include relation in Loopback

Tags: mysql, node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I want to get the result with include relation with where condition on include model.

```
return this.htcApi.find({
  include: [
    {
      relation: 'nmos',
      scope: {
        include: 'countries',
      },
    },
  ],
  where: { name:'Welcome', "nmos.name":'agile'}
});
```

This `where` is condition work for name of `htc` model not for `noms` module.

I want query like

```
Select htc.*, nmos.* FROM htc LEFT JOIN nmos ON nmos.id = htc.n_id where htc.name = 'abc' and nmos.name = 'abc';
```

How can add where condition on the "relation" table?

Answer (score 1):

Simply you need to add where clause in 'scope' object which lies inside the 'include' object. So the code would be like :

```
    return this.htcApi.find({
    include: [
      {
        relation: 'nmos',
        scope: {
          include: 'countries',
          where:{name:'agile'}
        },
      },
    ],
    where: { name:'Welcome'}
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you just need to add the property `where` within the `scope` property, like this:

```js
return this.htcApi.find({
  include: [
    {
      relation: 'nmos',
      scope: {
        include: 'countries',
        where: {
          and [
            { id: htc.n_id },
            { name: 'abc' },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  where: { name: 'abc' }
});
```

This should return the `htcApi` objects named 'abc' with the related `nmos` objects that have the name 'abc' and the id 'n_id'.

Comment: I assumed you already had it before making the request! Indeed it's not defined in the code provided